# What is the else statement syntax?

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am trying to make some code on swift that will allow me to type in a number, and it will print out it’s square root without using the square root command. But when I’m using the else if and else statements, swift is throwing me an error. The code will only answer to inputs that are within the range 1 to 10000.

```
    import Swift

    var input = readLine()

    var intInput = Int(input!)!
    print(intInput)

    if intInput < 1 || intInput > 10000{
    print("out of bounds")
    }


    if else {

for i in 1...100{

if intInput / i == i{
    print(intInput / i)
}
}

} 

else{
print("no root")
}
```

The error will say:

**closure expression is unused**

```
    else {
         ^
```

It will also say:

```
    Note: did you mean to use a ‘do’ statement?
    else {
         ^
```

Comment: If you fix your indentation, you'll probably spot an issue.

Comment: What is `if else {` supposed to do? Read up on using `if` in the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID127) book.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Swift but it looks the second else if statement is written in the wrong order ("if else") and also lacks a Boolean expression to test.
Also, I went ahead and improved the indentation for the sake of readability:

```
import Swift

var input = readLine()

var intInput = Int(input!)!
print(intInput)

if intInput < 1 || intInput > 10000
{
    print("out of bounds")
}
else if
{
    for i in 1...100
    {
        if intInput / i == i
        {
            print(intInput / i)
        }   
    }
} 
else
{
   print("no root")
}
```

Note that `else if` still lacks a condition, as it's up to you what you'd like to put there. This is likely just a simple case where a syntax error in one place gets identified in as an error in a completely different place, and can be pretty confusing.